# Does the iphone mail app inform safari of send/cancel choice of user?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, safari

Let's say I have a mailto link on an html5 mobile app viewed in iOS safari, like mailto:whatever@whatever.com. Clicking the link opens the iphone mail app modal composer. I want to thank the user for sending an email, so my web app needs to know if the user clicked send or clicked cancel.

After clicking "send" or "cancel" the modal closes. Does it report the send/cancel decision back to the browser? Does it report anything at all, or just return the user to the current state of the requesting web page?